# For each of the following regex, draw a DFA recognizing the corresponding language

Tags: dfa

I want to draw a DFA for each of the following regex.

The first one is that
(0|1)<sup>*</sup>110<sup>*</sup>

The second one is that
(1|110)<sup>*</sup>0

I wrote lots of diagrams, but I can't draw deterministic finite automata.

how can I get these?

Comment: What aspect of coming up with the DFAs are you having specific trouble with? Are you trying to convert the regexes to DFAs algorithmically, or are you just trying to find DFAs that accept the same language?

Comment: what's the difference of the two things?

Comment: They should end up with the same or very similar results, but as this is homework I'm assuming that you'll want to show your work, and so how you get there is different.